# Proof Verification: Show $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)=0$ given $f\in L^1$ and $f$ absolutely continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

so I am working through a packet of old exams and have came across three that are very similar. I was able to produce a proof (possibly wrong?) that works for all three, but it doesn't use all their additional assumptions. The questions are:

> Q1: Suppose that $f$ is integrable and absolutely continuous on $[0,\infty).$ If $f'\in L^1[0,\infty)$ prove that $f(x)\rightarrow0$ as $x\rightarrow\infty.$
>
> Q2: Let $f$ be absolutely continuous and nonnegative function on $[0,\infty)$ with $\int_0^\infty f(x)dx<\infty.$ If $f'(x)\leq M<\infty$ Lebesgue a.e. show that $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)=0.$
>
> Q3: Let $f:R\rightarrow R$ be continuously differentiable such that $f,f'\in L^1(R).$ Show that $f(x)\rightarrow0$ as $x\rightarrow\infty.$

Note first that for Q3 we have $f$ is absolutely continuous by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus (a combination of the basic and Lebesgue one).

So for these I suppose $f(x)\nrightarrow0$ which means $\exists\epsilon>0$ and $\{x_n\}_{n\geq1}$ s.t. $f(x_n)>\epsilon$ and $x_n\rightarrow\infty.$(assume these are at least 1 unit apart). Now since $f$ is absolutely continuous it is uniformly continuous, which means $\exists1>\delta>0$ s.t. $|x-y|<\delta\Rightarrow |f(x)-f(y)|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}.$ Noting
$$||f(x)|-|f(y)||<|f(x)-f(y)|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}\Rightarrow |f(y)|>\frac{\epsilon}{2},$$
we have
$$\int_{[x_n-\delta,x_n+\delta]}|f(x)|dx> \frac{\epsilon}{2}2\delta=\epsilon\delta.$$ Thus we have
$$\infty>\int_R |f(x)|dx > \int_{\cup[x_n-\delta,x_n+\delta]}|f(x)|dx=\sum_{n\geq1}\epsilon\delta=\infty$$ which is a contradiction and thus we have the result.

My concern is that I did not use all the given suppositions. I was just curious if I had gone astray anywhere. Thanks.

Comment: It seems your proof is valid. What is your definition of absolute continuity on a non-compact interval?

Comment: That is a very good question. Now that I stop to think about it I have only every seen the definition over bounded intervals. Do you happen to know the definition of AC on a nonbounded interval? However, this would only cause an issue for Q3 since AC implies (since it is built to be stronger) than uniformly continuous.

Comment: See wiki on [absolute continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity). You are right that AC implies uniform continuity (even on unbounded interval). However, the formulation in the questions suggests you might have an other definition than the usual one.

Comment: Okay, so we used the that $f\in AC [a,b]$ if for all $\epsilon>0$ there is $\delta$ s.t. if $\sum_{n\geq1} |b_n-a_n|<\delta$ then we have $\sum_{n\geq1} |f(b_n)-f(a_n)|<\epsilon,$ where $[a_n,b_n]$ are disjoint intervals contained in $[a,b].$ The definition on Wikipedia considers an arbitrary inverval $I$ on the real line, which would mean it also works for the real line, because it is an interval. Is this the definition you were referring to?

Comment: yes. the question is what definition you have on unbounded interval

Comment: So I may not understand your previous comment. Wouldn't the same definition hold, since there is no constraint on the interval, i.e. it doesn't say bounded (going off of the Wikipedia definition)?

Comment: if you have the same definition  on any interval, then AC implies UC. If your definition is "f is AC on any compact subinterval" (people use to call this *locally* AC), then you need that $f'$ is integrable, which implies $f$ is AC in the usual sense.

Comment: like I said previously, the questions suggest you seem to have an other def for AC on unbounded interval than say Wikipedia.